# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [org_apache_tomcat_websocket] was found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I have a spring-boot project that builds successfully but there is a problem deploying the war file, be it in tomcat or through maven plugins. When I manually place the war file in `*/webapps` and try to deploy it, I get the following error:

```
webapps\leave.war]
Oct 05, 2020 2:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validate
jar file
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.106\webapps\leave\WEB-I
NF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, sec
tion 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Oct 05, 2020 2:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validat
eJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.106\webapps\leave\WEB-I
NF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.21.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, secti
on 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class

Oct 05, 2020 2:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.

Oct 05, 2020 2:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
**SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngin
e[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/leave]]**
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(Lifecy
cleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:1007)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:98
3)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
2019)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executo
rs.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoo
lExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPo
olExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the n
ame [org_apache_tomcat_websocket] was found. This is not legal with relative ord
ering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider u
sing absolute ordering.**
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
a:1228)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
g.java:888)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5536)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more

Oct 05, 2020 2:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-
7.0.106\webapps\leave.war]
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catal
ina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].Stan
dardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/leave]]**
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:1011)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:98
3)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
2019)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executo
rs.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoo
lExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPo
olExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Oct 05, 2020 2:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.
106\webapps\leave.war] has finished in [67,451] ms
```

I have looked everywhere for a solution but nothing worked. I can't understand what I am supposed to do with absolute ordering since I don't even have a web.xml in my app. web-fragments.xml too doesn't have any < ordering > elements.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't mark your tomcat dependencies as provided. Mark them provided and rebuild your war.